# keep $_GET values except two specified

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form that i am using to search a database, the form method is GET:

```
<form method="get" action="">
```

Then my SQL Query selects from a database using the `$_GET` values

i run the SQL, then have this function - (http://pastebin.com/J3RL3MxC) - that i run underneath the query

So in total, it looks like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY company";
$i=0;
$array = ShowRecords($sql, "customer");
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {

}
```

and i echo my results in the foreach loop

this is working fine, however when navigating through the pages that the function creates i loose the `$_GET` values so i also loose what i have searched for

how can i keep the `$_GET` values but keep in mind that the `$_GET["pagenum"]` needs to be removed/changed so the page will change

I have already added this code:

```
$query_string = '?';
foreach($_GET as $q => $k) {
    if($q == 'id' or $q == 'pagenum') {
        //
    } else {
        if($q != '') {
            $query_string = '&'.$q.'='.$k;
        }
    }
}
```

at the top of my function to try to do what is needed ($_GET["id"] also needs to be removed) but its not keeping the values

What is the best way to keep all $_GET values except the specified ones?

P.S: I know i should be using PDO which i will be as soon as i have this issue sorted, i will then change my code to use PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http_build_query to build your query string instead of doing it manually:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

I would just store all of the request vars in an array and updated it as needed. When ready to output any links just use http_build_query to generate the query string

```
$request = $_GET;
unset($request['id']);
$request['pagenum'] = 2;
//etc

$query_string = '?' . http_build_query($request);
```

Comment: do i need to unset $request["id"] and pagenum?

Comment: and what does $request['pagenum'] = 2; do?

Comment: When you call http_build_query any variables in the $request array will be encoded into the query string. If you do not want the pagenum to be in a subsequent request then yes, unset it.

$request['pagenum'] = 2 is just an example of how to update the pagenum.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $id = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : NULL;

    $pagenum = isset($_GET["pagenum"]) ? $_GET["pagenum"] : NULL;

    if($id) {

    }

    if($pagenum) {

    }
```

Comment: where should i add this code? - can you explain please?